# Slim PHP: run routine before all routes

Tags: php, rest, slim

Is there a way to call a routine before each route in Slim PHP? I have a RESTful API and I want to validate the login before calling the API methods. My code looks like:

```
$app = new Slim();
$app->get('user/:id', function($id) use($app){
    $user = API::getUser($id);
    if($user){
        $app->response->status(200);
    }else{
        $app->response->status(404);
    }
});
```

The API makes the request and process a JSON response. I want to attach a precondition to allow the request, something like a callback. The API has a method `API::validate($token)` that returns `true` or `false`, I want to catch this and return status code 401 if authentication fails. Some methods like `API::login()` and `API::register()` don't need this validation.

Comment: The documentation covers 'dispatch hooks' which should allow you to do what you want. link: [Hooks-Overview](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Hooks-Overview). A 'login/logout' system for 'slim' can be found here: [Slim-ContextSensitiveLoginLogout](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Slim-ContextSensitiveLoginLogout)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll study it!  :D

Comment: @drux see if my answer helps you, to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i strongly advice you to read ALL the documentation. It isn't that big and you'll get a good introduction to the framework. http://docs.slimframework.com/

You don't need a routine but a hook that gets called before each routine. That's the way slim is structured.

A easy solution would be to keep the non protected pages in a array, and in that hook check if the request is protected or not.

```
$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function() use ($app) { 
   $publicRoutes = array('login', 'welcome');

   if(!in_array($app->router()->getCurrentRoute(), $publicRoutes) 
       // Get the token 
       $result = API::validate($token);
       if(!$result) {
       $app->redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

If you want to handle a more complex process with permissions levels, oauths, etc you'll rather use a Middleware. I like them because it's the right way to do this kind of tasks with Slim, and you can reuse them.

Comment: This will only work with Slim 2 as hooks have been deprecated since v3.

Comment: @Raven Do you know of a good post that helps "migrate" from "slim.before.dispatch" hook to whatever does the job on Slim 3?

Comment: @JESTech I believe you'd just implement some middleware

Comment: Checkout the current docs, middleware is what you're looking fore

Comment: @Gui: I'm afraid it's not enough, as I can read this in the v4 doco: "Route middleware is invoked only if its route matches the current HTTP request method and URI.". I have the exact same initial Q as how to go through an initial validation MW unconditionally before each route, and I can't find it easily in the Slim v4 doco.